# sql server 2012 select max date and use self join with other tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In a sql server 2012 I would like to join a table to other tables by CustomerNumber.

The following contains the table definition, example data, and the query I want to join to:

Here is the Inventory table with some data:

```
SELECT [InventoryID],
       [personID],
       [attributeID],
       [value],
       [cust_date]
FROM   [dbo].[Inventory]
WHERE  personID = 77170
       AND attributeID IN (562, 563, 564, 565)
ORDER  BY date DESC

InventoryID CustomerID attributeID value          [cust_date]
 262490684 77170         562          GA         2013-08-14 07:26:00
 262490683 77170         565          05/23/2014 2013-08-14 07:26:00
 262490682 77170         563           Acd         2013-08-14 07:26:00
 262490681 77170         564          08/14/2013 2013-08-14 07:26:00
 251784     77170         564          09/06/2007 2007-09-08 00:00:00
 250029     77170         562          MA         2007-09-08 00:00:00
 248287     77170         563          asp         2007-09-08 00:00:00
 251785     77170         564          09/07/2006 2006-09-08 00:00:00
 248286     77170         563          asp         2006-09-08 00:00:00
 250028     77170         562          MA         2006-09-08 00:00:00
 251783     77170         564          09/06/2006 2006-09-06 00:00:00
 249367     77170         562          LA         2006-09-06 00:00:00
 248285     77170         563          asp         2006-09-06 00:00:00
```

Here is the table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inventory](
[InventoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [attributeID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [value] [varchar](256) NULL,
 [cust_date] [smalldatetime] NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerData] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
 (
  [InventoryID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  
 =     ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 97) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inventory]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerData_Person] FOREIGN 
KEY   ([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer].([CustomerID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inventory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerData_Person]
GO
```

Here is the join to the Customer table that I would like assistance on and how to include the most current date where the attribute value is from '562' to '565':

```
select * from Customer
join dbo.Inventory cs575 on cs575.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID and cs575.attributeID IN    
('575','576','577')
join dbo.Inventory cs562 on cs562.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID and cs562.attributeID ='562'
left join dbo.Inventory cs563 on cs563.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID and cs563.[Date] =
cs562.  [Date] and cs563.attributeID ='563'
left join dbo.Inventory cs564 on cs564.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID and cs564.[Date] = 
cs562.[Date] and cs564.attributeID ='564'
left join dbo.Inventory cs565 on cs565.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID and cs565.[Date] =
cs562.[Date] and cs565.attributeID ='565'
```

1. The CustomerNumber is a foreign key reference to the other tables that need to be joined to.
2. I need to pick the most current cust_date for records where the attributeID is either: 52,53,54, or 55.
3. For each attribute value of 562, 563, 564, or 565, there usally between 0 to 50 rows in the inventory 
   table.
4. The attributes id  values are related to each other by cust_date.
   Thus in the Inventory table, I need to correlate these 4 attributes values to each other by finding maximum (most current). I do know that if I can locate the most current cust_date for one attribute I can relate each attribute to each other.

Can you tell me if I should use the query listed below to find the most current customer date, and/or do you have a query that just can suggest? If so, what would the query be? 
(**Note I found I had to use distinct on the select since each attribute value occurs more than one time in the table. Also attribute value of 52 is always required so it can be related to the other attribute values.)

```
   SELECT distinct CustomerNumber, cust_date
    FROM    cust_data
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT CustomerNumber, MAX(cust_date) AS cust_date
        FROM cust_data
            where attributeID = 562
            GROUP BY CustomerNumber
    ) AS T
    ON cust_data.CustomerNumber = T.CustomerNumber
    AND cust_data.cust_date = T.cust_date
```

How would you join the inventory table to the other tables using the customer number? There are times when there is no attribute values = 562, 563, 564, or 565?
Would you show me somet-sql that would solve this issue for me?

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired output ???

Comment: Don't post a new question.  Fix the original.

Comment: The original post was answered. I added the extra information to my original post here. I am hoping you can help me with all to join this data to the customer data. In addition, how would use the results of the maximum(cust_date) on part of my joins?